# change Language programmatically When Use "packageManager.getPermissionInfo"

Tags: android

How do I change the language When Use "packageManager.getPermissionInfo"?

```
PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
PermissionInfo pinfo=packageManager.getPermissionInfo(requestedPermissions[i], packageManager.GET_META_DATA);
listDataHeader.add(pinfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
```

I Change Configuration.local But Does not change Title and Description Permissions

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. You are getting string values from another process, and that process will be using the device's `Locale`, not your altered one.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not . Just Changed Resource Local